# Attempt to write using POI 5.0.0 give java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

So I downloaded Ant POI 5.0.0 and installed (to the best of my knowledge) it to my lib directory for use in my project.

when I try execute the following code:

```
XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(xlFile));
XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
```

I get "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook" but I know at least this directory and classes are there.  What other classes am I missing?

I'm also using the following imports.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Just for clarification, I have included my compiler command just in case I am missing something in my classpath as well.

javac -g -d ..\bin SomeApp.java -cp ..\src;..\lib\poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar;..\lib\poi-5.0.0.jar

Comment: If you're using external libraries, learn to use Maven or Gradle; it will make your life *much* easier.

Comment: I wish I could.  I am stuck in a corporate situation where I only have the basic compiler to work with and no other tools.  No version control, no IDE of any sort, etc.  Just Notepad and my wits.

Comment: mixing hssf and xssf imports seems strange without knowing the details. your classpath misses a few entries. In your restricted situation, I would download the [poi bin](https://poi.apache.org/download.html) archive and [use wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585). An example invocation can be found [on the PPT render page](http://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/ppt-wmf-emf-renderer.html) in "Instructions to run".

Comment: Build path now includes all libraries as a wildcard.  I also adjusted the import statement to:  [import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell; ]  It builds, but same error

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue, using Eclipse Enterprise Enterprise, version: 2019-06 (4.12.0). I had added apache-poi 5 jars in a user library
[image]

The project compiled fine. But when I run the web application on my location machine, was getting the error

What I was missing in eclipse was to include the following

[image]

After this, everything was working fine